# AsNoTracking using LINQ Query syntax instead of Method syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm interested in using `AsNoTracking` with my LINQ select queries to improve performance. I'm using Entity Framework 5 with Code First.

However, all of my queries are written using LINQ Query syntax and all of the `AsNoTracking` examples are shown using the Method syntax. I'm aware that `AsNoTracking` was created for the Method syntax but how do I achieve the same thing with the Query syntax?

Comment: AsNoTracking does NOT improve performance, because it lets EF contact the datasource on each call. Tracking is therefore also caching and improves performance.

Comment: Hi Robert, that's interesting because I've read a lot of articles that point towards AsNoTracking() giving a performance improvement when using SELECT's without needing to do any updating. ie http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking

Comment: Ok, to be precise: AsNoTracking is indeed faster when fetching data that has not been fetched before, because it does not need to check if the desired data is already present (which would be the fastest, of course).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You apply `AsNoTracking()` to the `DbSet`:

```
var result = (
    from person in ctx.People.AsNoTracking()
    select person)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works but I had to add 
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: what about joins? Do you apply them to those sets as well? EG: `from s in _context.Strategy.AsNoTracking() join sv in _context.StrategyVersion.AsNoTracking() on s.Id equals sv.StrategyId`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231982/1515209) answer

Answer (score 1):

Query syntax is replaced with method syntax by compiler, so there is no difference at all at the end.

Comment: I've tried using AsNoTracking() with my Query syntax but it doesn't even show up on Intellisense as an option.

Comment: On further thoughts, maybe I'm not using it correctly or I'm missing a library? ie var result = (from person in ctx.People select person).AsNoTracking().ToList()